# Phonegap contacts.find not working on device for IOS 6.0

Tags: cordova, ios-simulator, ios6, device

I have a sencha touch app using phonegap 1.9.  My code using the contacts.find method is:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

   // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
   //
    function onSuccess(contacts) {
         alert('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
            console.log(contacts[i]);
        }
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
   }
    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.multiple = true;
        var fields = ["phoneNumbers", "name"];
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
    }
```

Consistently my alert responds back with 'Found 0 contacts' when I run it on an Iphone 4 with IOS 6.0 installed.  It works perfectly in the IOS 6.0 simulator that I am running through xcode. Anybody have any idea why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You are running into a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-902) which has been fixed for PhoneGap 2.2.0. The first 2.2.0 release candidate will be out this week.